# How to replace a character with a word in Java

Tags: java, replace, postfix-notation, infix-notation

I have an input string like so which takes in infix expressions: `String str = "-(4-2)";`

My output string returns a string value in the form of postfix expressions: `4 2 - -`

How can I replace the `-` sign at the end of `4 2 - -` with `negate` so that my output looks like `4 2 - negate`?

I tried using `str.replace` but it won't work because you can only replace char with char or string with string.

My code for converting from infix to postfix expression:

```
private int precedence(Character character)
{
    switch (character)
    {
        case '+':
        case '-':
            return 1;

        case '*':
        case '/':
        case '%':
            return 2;
    }
    return 0;
}

@Override public T visitExp(ExpAnalyserParser.ExpContext ctx) {
    String postfix = "";
    Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<>();

    for (int i = 0; i< ctx.getText().length(); i++) {
        char c = ctx.getText().charAt(i);

        if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
            postfix += c;
        }

        else if (c == '(') {
            stack.push(c);
        }

        else if (c == ')') {
            while (!stack.isEmpty() && stack.peek() != '(') {
                postfix += " " + (stack.pop());
            }

            if (!stack.isEmpty() && stack.peek() != '(')
                System.out.println("Invalid Expression");
            else
                stack.pop();
        }
        else {
            postfix += " ";
            while (!stack.isEmpty() && precedence(c) <= precedence(stack.peek()))
                postfix += (stack.pop()) + " " ;
            stack.push(c);
        }
    }

    while (!stack.isEmpty()){
        postfix += " " + (stack.pop());
    }

    postfix = postfix.replace("%", "mod");

    try(FileWriter out = new FileWriter("postfix.txt")){
        out.write(postfix);
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("Infix Expression: " + ctx.getText());
    return (T) postfix;
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `str.replace("-", "negate")` or if you want specific parts of the `String` changed you'll have to do multiple `String` methods like `str.substring(str.lastIndexOf('-'))`

Comment: @youassassin I assume the problem was OP used `'-'` rather than `"-"` right?

Comment: Can you give a [mcve] to show what you have tried?

Comment: Surely your postfix converter knows when it has found a negation rather than a subtraction, so it can directly output `negate` rather than you having to hack the output; how do you determine the last `-` is a negation anyway and not just a subtraction, as in say `4 3 2 - -`? Otherwise the problem is just "How do I replace the last character of a string with a string", which is what your title is; have we got an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/222560) here?

Comment: @KenY-N You have a good point. I will edit in my postfix converter code so you can see how I did it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ReplaceAll, which sounds counterintuitive, uses regular expressions, and so you can specify the minus at the end of the String:

```
-> str.replaceAll ("-$", "negate");
|  Expression value is: "4 2 - negate"
|    assigned to temporary variable $14 of type String
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to remove the last character using `substring` then concatenate your word to the end:

```
str = str.substring(0, str.length() - 1) + "negate";
```